# Unconfirmed transaction simple advice

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I am new to bitcoin and made a beginner mistake. I sent bitcoin from Mycelium wallet to coinbase wallet. Mycelium offered some rely small fees without warning, they only warned that if you pick 0 it might not happen. I picked a small fee as I considered that I am not in hurry. Now the Mycellium says transaction its confirmed and coinbase says its pending. If I understand Blockcypher correctly it says my BTC is received but no send. Is there anything I can do but hope that someone mines the rest of the block? If yes can you please tell me what in a simple way? amount is like 0.08... BTC so its relatively high for a student...

Comment: "If I understand Blockcypher correctly it says my BTC is received but no send." If you were to provide a transaction id or address, other peeople could check your assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry to much yet. These days Bitcoin transactions take their time to be confirmed on both sides. A transaction that would have previously been confirmed successfully in one hour, can these days take a day or more.
With the small fee you offered for the transaction you didn't exactly help in speeding up the process.